# Trouble with accessing a member function

Tags: c++

I'm using the EasyBMP library. This library has a method:

```
int red = image(i, j)->Red;  
// Gets the value stored in the red channel at coordinates (i, j) of the BMP named image and stores it into the int named red.
```

Here's the code that I have:

`int red = images[i](x, y)->Red;`//images is a dynamic array, I'm using a for loop here

images is a member variable of the class with this declaration:

```
Image **images;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
scene.cpp:195: error: ‘*(((Image**)((const Scene*)this)->Scene::images) + ((Image**)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’ cannot be used as a function
```

However, this works fine, but I dont know why the above doesnt work:

```
images[i]->TellWidth() //gets the width of the image
```

I understand where its getting mixed up, but I dont know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you have an array of pointers to `Image`s. Subscripting the array gives you a pointer. You have to dereference the pointer first before you can call functions on it.

```
int red = (*(images[i]))(x, y)->Red;
```

Note that an extra pair of parentheses are needed because the dereference operator `*` has a lower precedence than the function call operator `()`. The subscripting operator `[]` has the same precedence as the function call operator `()`.

```
// Order: array subscript, function call, arrow
int red = images[i](x, y)->Red
// Order: array subscript, function call, pointer dereference, arrow
int red = *(images[i])(x, y)->Red;   
// Order: array subscript, pointer dereference, function call, arrow
int red = (*(images[i]))(x, y)->Red;
```

If you're in doubt about the precedence order of the operators, use parentheses!

If the whole array to pointer thing still confuses you, think about an array of `ints`:

```
int* arrayOfInts;
```

When you subscript an `arrayOfInts`, you get an `int`:

```
int val = arrayOfInts[0];
```

Now you have an array of pointers to `Images`s. Take the above example and replace `int` with `Image*`:

```
Image** arrayOfPointersToImages = GetArrayOfPointersToImages();
Image* ptr = arrayOfPointersToImages[0];
```

But why do you have an array of pointers to `Image`s like that? Can't you use a `std::vector<Image>`?

Comment: No I have no choice, I must have it like this

Comment: @iRobot: I'm not convinced that you need it like this. Is it how the EasyBMP library is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
int red = (*(images[i]))(x, y)->Red;
```

`images` is a table of pointers, so `images[i]` gives you pointer to `Image` and to call `operator()` you have to use `*` to get the value of `images[i]` pointer.